# how will an in place upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 affect any installed programs

Tags: upgrade, wacom, digikam

I just tried to install 18.04 on a new system and discovered that in  18.04 the three packages I use for photography that interfaced fine don't seem to work as well, or at all. the three packages are DigiKam, Gimp and the Wacom driver for my Bamboo tablet. In 16.04 the version installed would read Gimp .xcf files but in 18.04 the higher level version does not. and the Wacom tablet I use is not fully supported and will recognise the pen. So I loaded 16.04 and everything works as before. 
My question is: if I do an in place upgrade to 18 or 17 will the install also upgrade the DigiKam tablet drivers and Gimp or can I keep the current versions that work under 16.04. I want to upgrade because 16.04 seems to have issues with networking and programs gray out crash or hang for periods of time.
thanks.

Comment: An upgrade seems likely to replace all the 16.04 software with the same 18.04 versions that didn't work well for you, including newer drivers. You cannot mix the two versions without great skill.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions here but let me answer your wacom driver question.

I do not know specifically which tablet you are using (lsusb | grep Wacom) so I do not know if a manually installed driver is necessary in your case. If you are relying on a manually installed input-wacom driver, you will need to manually install input-wacom each time you change kernels. (Your kernel will change as part of the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.)

Explanation: When you manually install input-wacom, you run "./configure" or "./autogen.sh" so that the Makefile will know where to place the driver that you build. The "wacom.ko" file (the driver) is subsequently installed in the "extra" directory associated with the kernel you were running when you ran "./configure" or "./autogen.sh" for example:

```
/lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/extra/wacom.ko
```

When you upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 your system will start running a new kernel and you will need to re-install the driver, if a manually installed driver is necessary. You will also need to re-install anytime your kernel changes, for example your kernel may change as part of the normal "sudo apt upgrade" process.

Comment: The tablet is the Bamboo as mentioned in the post, works great in 16.04 with pen or as a oversized touch pad, though I use it mostly with the pen for retouching photos as its a much more natural feel using a pen rather than a mouse. I did try as you suggested before redoing the install back to 16.04 and it didn't work. I have seemed to have figured out how to resolve the wifi network issue. Thanks  for the quick response to both responders.

Comment: For future reference, there are multiple generations of the the Bamboo line, the lsusb command helps differentiate them.